Forwarding traffic two consecutive proxies with custom syntax in URL
I would need to send requests to my public website (or any other example website) using two consecutive proxies. The first one would receive request to https://123-456-789-123-8080-example.com/path. In this path is hidden IP address of second proxy 123.456.789.123:8080 to which I want to forward the cleared request https://example.com/path. I would also need to receive all the responses on the sub-requests for downloading the images within the target website and so on.
The result would be to start google chrome or any other browser with the first proxy of the chain, entering https://123-456-789-123-8080-example.com/path into address bar within Chrome and it would resolve the request and load the website just like I would go straight through, without the proxies between client and server.
I tried to configure it using nginx:
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location ~ ^/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)-(\d+)-(.*) {
            # Capture the upstream IP, port, and cleaned path
            set $proxy_ip $1;
            set $proxy_port $2;
            set $clean_path /$3;

            # Rewrite URL to remove IP and port, leaving only the target path
            rewrite ^/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)-(\d+)-(.*) $clean_path break;

            # Proxy pass only the IP and port; Nginx appends the rewritten path
            proxy_pass http://$proxy_ip:$proxy_port;

            # Optional: Pass other headers as needed
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

which was unsuccessful. Do you have any idea how could I configure nginx (or really any other open-souce proxy software) to do it?
I was also looking into pingora as library in Rust for purposes like these but I was unsuccessful using it.

I'm looking for better option
I was able to resolve it using mitm proxy. It is really slow (300 ms for response) but it works. I needed to create add-on url.py which consists of this code
